# Esconder formulário ao pressionar tecla

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Eu criei um form, eu não quero usar botão minimizar ou maximizar, eu quero usar por exemplo ao pressionar "F1" meu formulário fique oculto e apertar F1 novamente ele volta a aparecer.

Tentei isto, mas sem sucesso:

```
       private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F1)
       {

            Form1 fm = new Form1();
            fm .Hide();

       }
   }
```

Comment: da uma olhada nesse link, talvez ajude https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/8d299b9e-bea2-4daf-8705-1394e3e91ca1/maximizando-minimizando-e-arrastando-o-form?forum=vscsharppt

Comment: vlw vitor, me ajudou bastante desisti do esquema das telcas nao funciona no meu form usei um buttom pra minimizar mesmo.

Comment: @CerraossoUC A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Você está criando um nome formulário e escondendo ele, não pode, tem que esconder o atual:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) => if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F1) this.Hide();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/HideFormByKey.cs).